# Elasticsearch query results return wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a query for server logs. The search is returning results but there are a couple of issues.

1) I'm specifying the server name, yet I'm getting results back for other servers in the same domain.

2) Even though I'm specifying the query get results back from the past hour, they're coming back from two hours before, i.e. if I perform the search at 1pm, the results are returning from 12pm. The search returns the correct results if I specify sorting by timestamp but this seems to take longer for the results to appear so I would rather not do that unless I have to.

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Here's my query (with edited log name and server name):

```
var searchParams = {
index: 'logs*',
    "body": {
      "from" : 0, "size": 50,
      "sort": [
        {
          "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc",
            "unmapped_type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      ],
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                      "match" : {"gl2_source_input" : "579f7b6696d78a4f6cbfa745"},
                      "match" : {"source" : "server01.fakedomain.com"},
                      "match" : {"EventID" : "5145"}
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1h",
                              "lte": "now/m",
                              "time_zone": "-05:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
              "must_not": []
            }
        },

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here:

1. If you want to match a keyword exactly, then use a `term` query on a `keyword` type field.
2. Unless you're interested in your queries being scored, you should use a `filter` clause instead of the `must` clause.

So your query can look something like this (assuming that your filter fields are `keyword` type fields).

```
var searchParams = {
index: 'logs*',
    "body": {
      "from" : 0, "size": 50,
      "sort": [
        {
          "timestamp": {
            "order": "desc",
            "unmapped_type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      ],
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    { "term" : {"gl2_source_input" : "579f7b6696d78a4f6cbfa745"} },
                    { "term" : {"source" : "server01.fakedomain.com"} },
                    { "term" : {"EventID" : "5145"} },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1h",
                              "lte": "now/m",
                              "time_zone": "-05:00"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  There's a missing comma after the last bracket of the first search term but it worked once I added that.  After I posted the question, I copied a query from our Graylog server and got it working but your solution is MUCH cleaner and MUCH faster.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Good catch on the comma, I'll edit the answer.